# Python 2.7. Parse input parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, argparse

Good time of the day! First of all, let me say that I'm a newbie in Python world. I've problems with parsing input parameters. At this moment **I'm using Python 2.7** and module which is called `argparse`. I'm trying to design simple application which will be able to parse simple input parameters. Here is a short example:

> my_app.py sync --force

Second example:

> my_app.py patch --branch

I see that for this I can use `add_argument` which can work with positional and optional arguments. Like in my case I want to have few positional (but optional at the same time) and few optional arguments.
To do that I've design small script

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My App')
    parser.add_argument('sync', type=bool, const=True, nargs='?')
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--force', dest='sync_force', type=bool, const=True, nargs='?')
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--branch', type=str, const=True, nargs='?')
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--url', type=str, const=True, nargs='?')
    parser.add_argument('patch', type=bool, const=True, nargs='?')
    parser.add_argument('revert', type=bool, const=True, nargs='?')
    parser.add_argument('verify', type=bool, const=True, nargs='?')

    values = parser.parse_args()

    if values.revert:
        handler.revert()
    else:
        parser.print_help()
```

I see that I can use `nargs='?'` to specify the positional parameter as optional, but each time when I'm calling my script it shows like I got '*sync*' as input parameter, even if I specified '*patch*'. So, I think that it shows just first added element.
Could you tell me what's wrong and where is a problem?

**Update:**
I'm trying to achieve a situation when I will be able to have only one positional argument at the same time(and at least one, but with any additional optional parameters). For example

> my_app.py sync
>
> my_app.py path
>
> my_app.py verify --force
>
> my_app.pyrevert --branch

Comment: _I’m using Python 2.7_ Why?

Comment: Can you give more information about the use options for the parameters? For example, should only one of `sync`, `patch`, `revert`, `verify` be present at a time? Try to give all the different options your program accepts. Because as it sounds you should either use a Mutual Exclusive group, or sub-commands. Hard to recommend which one without more details

Comment: Replace `patch/revert/verify` with `add_argument('cmd',choices=['patch', 'revert', 'verify'])`, and check `values.cmd` after parsing.

Comment: `type=bool` is wrong.  If you want true/false value use `action='store_true`.  `nargs='?'` has it's uses, but I don't think it is useful in any of these.  Same for `const`.  Practice with the simplest default `store` and `store_true` actions.

Comment: Unless you are currently employed to maintain Python 2 code, you should switch to Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My App')
    parser.add_argument('cmd', choices=['sync','patch', 'revert','verify'])
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--force', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--branch')
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--url')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
    if args.cmd in ['revert']:
        print('handler.revert()')
    else:
        parser.print_help()
```

testing

```
1243:~/mypy$ python stack60327766.py 
usage: stack60327766.py [-h] [-f] [-b BRANCH] [-u URL]
                        {sync,patch,revert,verify}
stack60327766.py: error: too few arguments
1244:~/mypy$ python stack60327766.py revert
Namespace(branch=None, cmd='revert', force=False, url=None)
handler.revert()
1244:~/mypy$ python stack60327766.py revert -f -b foobar -u aurl
Namespace(branch='foobar', cmd='revert', force=True, url='aurl')
handler.revert()
1244:~/mypy$ python stack60327766.py verify-f -b foobar -u aurl
usage: stack60327766.py [-h] [-f] [-b BRANCH] [-u URL]
                        {sync,patch,revert,verify}
stack60327766.py: error: argument cmd: invalid choice: 'verify-f' (choose from 'sync', 'patch', 'revert', 'verify')
1245:~/mypy$ python stack60327766.py verify -f -b foobar -u aurl
Namespace(branch='foobar', cmd='verify', force=True, url='aurl')
usage: stack60327766.py [-h] [-f] [-b BRANCH] [-u URL]
                        {sync,patch,revert,verify}

My App

positional arguments:
  {sync,patch,revert,verify}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -f, --force
  -b BRANCH, --branch BRANCH
  -u URL, --url URL
```

Comment: Awesome! But is it possible to do same without "cmd" parameter?

Comment: Do what without the "cmd" parameter?  You don't like the name?  Or don't want a positional that accepts words like "revert"?  What I've shown is a step away from the subcommands recommended by @AKX.

Comment: "cmd" is the one positional argument that you want.

Answer (score 0):

`argparse` has [native support for subcommands](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands).

Adapting from the above-linked documentation,

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
sync_parser = subparsers.add_parser('sync')
patch_parser = subparsers.add_parser('patch')
revert_parser = subparsers.add_parser('revert')
verify_parser = subparsers.add_parser('verify')
```

etc. is probably what you're looking for.

Beyond that, I can only recommend the [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) library for a more fluent interface for CLIs.

Comment: Almost, but in general, it doesn't work with overall logic. Mainly it requires to specify `--foo` as the first parameter and only then you will be allowed to put subparser. Like "-f sync" instead of "sync -f"